# MySQL: Update multiple rows based on 2 fields using only a single query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Is there a proper way to simplify this query from using 3 separate queries to only using 1? As you can see each `INSERT` is based on the fields `option` and `user_id`.

```
DB::update('
    UPDATE bd_useroptions SET `value` = ?
        WHERE `option` = ? AND user_id = ?',
    array($page_pagination, 'page_pagination', $user->id));

DB::update('
    UPDATE bd_useroptions SET `value` = ?
        WHERE `option` = ? AND user_id = ?',
    array($newsletter, 'newsletter', $user->id));

DB::update('
    UPDATE bd_useroptions SET `value` = ?
        WHERE `option` = ? AND user_id = ?',
    array($shortcuts, 'shortcuts', $user->id));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DB::update("UPDATE bd_useroptions SET value = CASE
    WHEN option = 'page_pagination' THEN ?
    WHEN option = 'newsletter' THEN ?
    WHEN option = 'shortcuts' THEN ?
    END
WHERE user_id = ?",
array($page_pagination, $newsletter, $shortcuts, $user->id));
```

Comment: Just added missing END

Comment: I thought so. But it's no problem I already noticed it and added it to my project.

Comment: Just to emphasize on the point that using `WHERE` is important. If you don't include it, all other `value` fields would be `NULL`.

Comment: @enchance True. Other security measure is to add `ELSE value` - result the same, but obviously with `where` might be much faster and that's the way to go.